# SBS 2008 Redirection visibility issues - want to move off SBS 2008

Tags: files, windows-sbs-2008, redirection, directory

I inherited an SBS2008 server which had a corrupt or otherwise lost userid which was used to setup redirects, etc.

I was able to break in by enabling the Administrator ID and resetting the password.

Now, I cannot see the redirected folders. Using TreeSize Pro, I can see the folders and their contents.

From a user machine with user's userid and password, I cannot see the folders or files, but the shortcut which accesses those files via an application works correctly, so the files are accessible.

Unfortunately, the previous person (who is no longer here) was not taking backups, so I am in a precarious position.

Using TreeSize Pro, I can copy the folders, sudb-folders, and files to a Windows 7 Pro computer, but even on this computer, I cannot see the files except through TreeSize.

I THINK I NEED TO MAKE THE FILES COPIED TO THE WINDOWS 7 PRO MACHINE VISIBLE AND ACCESSIBLE, so that I can see what I have, determine if I can run apps against them etc. - So that I can then reload SBS2008 from scratch and set everything up correctly.

The application using these files will run on SBS 2008 or on Windows 7 Pro, so I am OK there.

The application is mission critical and cannot be down for more than an hour or two and corrupting the data (without access to a proper backup) would be a disaster! Since I don't have proper backups (except what I could copy using TreeSize), I'm afraid to do surgery on the SBS 2008 machine to make the files visible.

SO, I THINK THE SAFEST COURSE OF ACTION IS TO MAKE THE FILES COPIED TO THE WINDOWS 7 MACHINE VISIBLE, ESTABLISH A WORKING SYSTEM, AND THEN GO FROM THERE.

I've changed the hidden attribute and the owner of the folders and files copied to the Windows 7 machine, but they are still not visible.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the files might be recognised as a "System File".
Using the "attrib" command line utility on one of the files on your Windows 7 machine, try:

```
attrib -S -H fullpathtofile
```

This command will remove the SYSTEM and HIDDEN attributes from the file, and should make it visible if that's the cause of this issue.

You can also use the following command to see what attributes ARE applied to this file:

```
attrib fullpathtofile
```

If the application has applied these attributes for a reason, I might suggest trying to contact the application vendor to get further information about how to work with the files directly.  There may be another way that's not immediately evident.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The files are not visible due to SBS 2008 Redirection. Unfortunately, the userid used to create the redirections is corrupt and cannot be accessed. The files are not visible from the Administrator id because it was not authorized to view them.